# Django generates different queries for exclude with Q and with simple filter lookup

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-q

There is a simplified scheme of my models:

```
class A(Model):
   name = CharField()

class B(Model):
   a = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b', editable=False, null=False)
   valid = models.NullBooleanField(default=None)
```

So django generates two different queries for following statements:

1) Exclude with Q object

```
A.objects.filter().exclude(Q(b__valid=True))
SELECT a.name FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (a.id = b.a_id) WHERE NOT (b.valid = True)
```

2) Exclude with field lookup

```
A.objects.filter().exclude(b__valid=True)
SELECT a.name FROM a WHERE NOT 
    (a.id IN 
        (SELECT U1.a_id FROM b U1 WHERE 
            (U1.valid = True and U1.a_id IS NOT NULL)))
```

Is this normal behavior? It produces different queries and in result we can get different items from database.
For example we have following database tables:

```
A
id    name
1     Seagull
2     Weasel
3     Deer

B
id    a_id    valid
1     1       1
1     1       0
```

First statement will return 1-Seagull object and second statement will return empty queryset. It doesn't look like correct behavior.

Comment: It seems I get the difference right after I have posted question. First statement should exclude b with valid = True and second should exclude a which has b with valid = True.

Comment: Maybe it's not explicit, but I guess it works correctly.